# How can i create an index on the PRIMARY filegroup?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX index
ON table (column1)
INCLUDE (column2, column3) ON ????;
```

table is partitioned into 3 filegroups
I want to create index physically stored in the PRIMARY filegroup
How can i do it?

Comment: Although I can guess what the database is, you should tag the question with the database (and version) that you are using.

Comment: sorry about that, first time posting a question :p will tag the next questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is correct - you'll just however need to escape out `PRIMARY` with `[]`, i.e.:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX1
ON table (column1)
INCLUDE (column2, column3) 
ON [PRIMARY];
```

If you are moving an existing index, you'll need to [drop the existing one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175905.aspx):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX1
ON table (column1)
INCLUDE (column2, column3) 
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)
ON [PRIMARY];
```